# nextjs: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I use `sweetalert2` to show popups:

```
export default function Home() {
    const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        MySwal.fire({
            showConfirmButton: false,
            customClass: {
                container: "swalPopup"
            },
            html:<Link href={"/profile/dashboard"}><a>TEST</a></Link>,
        })
    }, []);

    return ('<div>Home</div>')
}
```

After a popup is shown, I click on `TEST` and I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')

Call Stack
linkClicked
node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (50:11)
onClick
node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js (200:16)
```

Without `sweetalert2`, `<Link>` it works fine otherwise I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try one of these:

```
<Button type="button" onClick={(e) => router.push('/profile/dashboard')}>
    Test
</Button>
```

or

````
<Link href="/">
    <a onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, "//profile/dashboard")}>Test</a>
</Link>```
````

Comment: The first way work fine. thank you